# Error calling NpqsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar geting DB time

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a method that gets the DateTime from the DB with the following code:

NpgsqlCommand cmd = ActiveConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOW()";

object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return (DateTime)obj;

Sometimes an InvalidCastException is thrown when converting the result to DateTime. Sometimes the result (obj) is null.
Any idea why this is happening? do you have any ideas on where to start scratching?

TIA
José Tavares

Comment: Which version are you using? Latest versions have better type handling which van help you with castexception problems. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have 2.0.7 version. After solving the concurrency problems I stop getting this error. I now have a Connection Pool instead of managing the access to the only connection.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no NOW() function in postgresql. Use this instead:

```
//create NpgsqlCommand instance, cmd
cmd.CommandText = "select current_timestamp";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out dt);
return dt;
```

Comment: There is a now() function in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Yes the function exists. Most of the times the function works, but sometimes I get the problem stated.

Comment: Is it related with concurrency?